# Долго не выключается компъютер

Tags: windows, windows-7

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение такой проблемы. ОС Win 7, после выключения компьютера он почему-то стал долго не выключаться. Пишет завершение работы - и все, оператива работает индикатор мигает. Раньше такого не было, но минуты 2-3 приходится ждать, пока он выключится. И еще раньше стоял виджет, но мне он как бы надоел, и я его хотел удалить, но не смог, так как файл заблокирован другой программой, и снести этот виджет не получается, и постоянно он открывается при включении компа, хотя уже стоит другой виджет, а этот сам автоматом лезет на рабочий стол сверху на другие виджеты. Приходится его постояно закрывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посмотрел какие события возникают при выключении. Из них будет ясно, что происходит в эти 2 минуты.

Comment: нашел проблемку так что все нормик

Answer (score 1):

Ответ кроется в вопросе. В системе установлено множество дополнительных приложений. Перед тем, как выключить компьютер, ОС должна "выключить" все эти дополнительные приложения. А они, в зависимости от их природы и исполнения, могут отключаться долго. Вам нужно просмотреть список установленных программ и удалить ненужные.

Comment: Дело в том, что программ не так уж и много, комп чистится постоянно, по работе, реагированию на мышу и клавы нареканий нет; по скорости - все отлично, но вот проблема остается не решенной. Системник: 6 ядер, 6 гиг оперативы, ну и так далее. Компу еще нет пол года, как с магазина, еще на гарантии. Думаю, может оператива выгружает так долго, не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Просто, он переходит в спящий режим а не выключается, надо зайти в панель упрвления, -электорпитание, там в настройках плана электропитания установить функции кнопок выключения.